# Is try...catch a control flow pattern?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages

Is `try...catch` a *control flow pattern* such as `if-than-else-elseif` or `switch-case-break-default`?

Would another definition be better than *control flow pattern* for it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Exceptions

Comment: *Control flow pattern* is not a formally defined concept. The informal definition suggests that try/catch blocks are an example.

Comment: What is your definition of *control flow pattern*? Without a precise, unambiguous, objective specification of what, *exactly* you mean by *control flow pattern*, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I disagree, I said "such as" and gave examples which you and many others here know very well from experience as common programming practice --- and to formalize "a set of keywords common in abstract programming languages and commonly used together to created control flow in any given context".